# DatePickerDialog missing days

Tags: android

I'm having a very strange behaviour when I create a DatePickerDialog. There's no special theme or any customization and I'm getting all the text in white on a white background, so days are not showed. You can see a screenshot here:

[image]

Any idea of what can be wrong?

*Edit*

Here you have the code where I create the dialog, nothing special.

```
        Date date = DateUtils.getDateMinusYears(18);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                mTextDateBirth.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                mImgIconDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btnDate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.global_background_with_border_orange);
            }
        }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Is this on the emulator or on a device?

Comment: And can you show a simple code example which duplicates this?

Comment: I've tried in both and it doesn't work on any of them.

Comment: I added the code to the original message, I guess I might have some global theme settings that overrides something on the pickers.

Comment: Try to a use a style with`DatePickerDialog`.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with color

```
 <style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        </style>
```

java

```
     private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;


               final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new 
 DatePickerDialog(yourActivity.this, R.style.datepicker,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                                {
                                    youredittext.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
```